# Setting up vagrant in virtualbox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I just downloaded `virtualbox`, installed `centos` and development tools.

I also installed `vagrant` and installed it, in `windows 7`.

It says in the vagrant page, you can install vagrant in `virtualbox` using

```
$ vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
$ vagrant up
```

But, I am getting `vagrant command not found` Are they supposed to be installed inside one another? because, if I download/install them separately, I don't know how my `virtualbox` could even understand the `vagrant` command.

Comment: I'm confused, where did you install centos and where did you install virtualbox? It looks like you are trying to run vagrant from your linux VM(?). Assuming you want a linux vagrant VM, install both vagrant and virtualbox on Windows then `vagrant init ...` and `vagrant up` from cmd prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vagrant and VirtualBox are entirely separate. Vagrant uses VirtualBox by calling [VBoxManage](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) commands. Both vagrant and vboxmanage binaries need to be on your system PATH variable.

In Windows you can check and adjust the PATH as shown here: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: So, you are saying that vagrant does not operate inside the virtualbox? Now, I have understood that vagrant is separate, and only makes use of the vboxmanage api/interface to connect to virtualbox, how can I add a path in windows to points vagrant to the vbox manage? @Mike D

Comment: Btw, I know how to add/modify path variable, just not which one for this use case

Comment: @robue-a7119895 correct, vagrant, using the virtualbox provider, controls virtualbox machines. a little taste of that code is here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/v1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/driver/base.rb#L26

secondly, on Windows, the vagrant installer by default adds `c:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin` to your path. In that `bin` dir, you should see `vagrant.exe`.